# Bash: preventing overriding privacy of a variable declared on nested functions

Tags: bash

I have a global variable in a nested function

```
function nested() {
    output='not today';

    echo "${output}";
}

function test() {
   local output="$(nested)";

   echo ${output};
}
```

And I would like to keep it global for other purposes. I see that Bash offers the possibility to override the privacy of it. But I don't know how to prevent that.

Is it possible to prevent only this, specifically?

Comment: Name collisions are one reason why globals are in general a bad idea, why would you want to prevent a local of the same name?   Encapsulated functions are easier to debug, easier to read, and can be reused in multiple scripts.  `local` good, global bad.

Comment: The script I am creating have a very specific usage for very specific variables that I want global sometimes and most of the times I use only local. But having plenty of local variables makes it harder to do complex code considering the fact this variables have to go up the tree at some point... (on my code, of course)

Comment: Bash uses dynamic scoping, not lexical scoping. See [Scope of Local Variables in Shell Functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282557/scope-of-local-variables-in-shell-functions)

Comment: I do not quite understand you. What's your expected behavior/output?

Comment: My expected behavior is that local output would not have any effect into forcing the previous declared global output to local.

Comment: In bash 4.2+ you can use `declare -G var=foo` to modify a global variable even if there is a local variable in scope of the same name. However, in your example, the `nested` function is called in a subshell so no variables will be changed at all in the calling script.